# Setting the $\texttt{state_preparation}$ for $\texttt{AmplificationProblem()}$ in the scope of Grover's algorithm

Tags: qiskit, programming, grovers-algorithm, amplitude-amplification

I am having trouble setting the `state_preparation` parameter of `AmplificationProblem()` from `qiskit.algorithms`.
I’d like to apply a **generalized version of Grover** on only one of the multiple registers in my circuit.

The total number of registers in the circuit is 3.
After several computation steps (including quantum counting algo) the target register gets in a superposition of **non-uniform** basis states - also, it is entangled with the other two registers.

According to the  [documentation](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.algorithms.AmplificationProblem.html), `state_preparation` parameter takes just a `QuantumCircuit` (sometimes also referred to as Operator).
Since my circuit includes the `Initialize()` method from `qiskit.extensions.initialize` (for the other two registers), i.e. a non-unitary operation, there exists no inverse.

My questions are two-fold:

- What should I pass as the `state_preparation` parameter? I just need
  one specific `QuantumRegister` to be passed, but I do not have a circuit or operator for only that register (have only the full QuantumCircuit of the entire algorithm).
- Per the [documentation/tutorials](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.GroverOperator.html), the state_preparation operator $\mathcal{A}$ should be invertible  - but the `Initialize()` method introduces a qubit reset, which is non-unitary. How can I circumvent this?

So as a summary I'm wondering what would be the best approach to avoid passing the entire circuit to the `state_preparation`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass a circuit, but you can just remove the resets from your circuit with the `initialize` instruction as

```
>>> from qiskit.circuit import QuantumCircuit
>>> from qiskit.transpiler.passes import RemoveResetInZeroState
>>> init = QuantumCircuit(3)
>>> init.initialize([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], init.qubits)
>>> init.draw()
     ┌──────────────────────────────┐
q_0: ┤0                             ├
     │                              │
q_1: ┤1 Initialize(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) ├
     │                              │
q_2: ┤2                             ├
     └──────────────────────────────┘
>>> stateprep = RemoveResetInZeroState()(init.decompose())
>>> stateprep.draw()
     ┌──────────────────┐
q_0: ┤0                 ├
     │                  │
q_1: ┤1 disentangler_dg ├
     │                  │
q_2: ┤2                 ├
     └──────────────────┘
```

Now you can pass `stateprep` as the `state_preparation` argument in the `AmplitudeProblem`.

Comment: Thanks! This indeed removes the `resets` from the initialized circuit. However, passing the entire circuit (which includes `stateprep` initialize) to `state_preperation` throws an error. I'll probably split the original question in two, to be able to describe the problem better.

Answer (score 1):

The points that I learned about passing the correct parameter `state_preparation` to `AmplificationProblem()` are as below:

1. The operator $\mathcal{A}$ should be invertible. Therefore the
   circuit that we pass should not include any non-unitary operations
   e.g. `reset` (for example, if you have `.initialize()` somewhere in your circuit).
2. The circuit should not include `ClassicalRegister`.
3. The `oracle` passed to the amplification method should be in the size of the **circuit's width** ($\mathcal{A}$). Although the target `QuantumRegister`, that we aim to apply amplification on, has smaller width!

For (1.), the approach that @Cryoris suggested, is working properly. Hence accepted his answer.
There is still an issue with the result of `AmplificationProblem()`. For that, I've opened a separate [question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/22101/understanding-qiskits-textttamplificationproblem-behaviour).
In addition, I think passing the entire circuit creates an overhead of an unnecessary number of qubits to the amplification method.